# Extract value between double quotes

Tags: awk

My query is to extract the value between double quotes `""`. Sample input is:

> 10.219.41.68 - - - [11/Jun/2014:10:23:04 -0400] Sec:0 MicSec:1797 "GET /balancer-manager HTTP/1.1" 200 28980 "-" "curl/7.15.5
>   (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3
>   libidn/0.6.5"

I have large log files, so values can be vary for each line, need to extract the value between first occurrence of double quotes…

Expected output:

```
GET /balancer-manager HTTP/1.1
```

Anyone have any idea then please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804673/escaping-separator-within-double-quotes-in-awk

Answer (score 37):

You can just use [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) for this:

```
$cut -d '"' -f2 < logfile
GET /balancer-manager HTTP/1.1
```

`-d '"'` tells `cut` to use a double quote as its field delimiter. `-f2` tells it to take the second field, which is between the first and second quotes - or the first quoted string, exactly what you want.

Comment: How to print all even numbered columns in cut easily like `%!cut -d '"' -f2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58`?

Answer (score 13):

A way using `awk`

```
awk -F'"' '$0=$2' file
```

If for some absurd reason your HTTP methods are actually `0` and you want to output these

```
awk -F'"' '{$0=$2}1' file
```

Comment: What if `$2` is null?

Comment: Then it wont print it ? The same as it wont in your answer. Only difference is your answer will print a blank line for every record with no $2.

Comment: No, my answer print a blank like. And imagine that the value is `0`, not only null?

Comment: I'd imagine given the context of the question that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick responses...Its really helpful for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it many ways.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{print $2}' file
GET /balancer-manager HTTP/1.1
```

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'"' -anle 'print $F[1]' file
GET /balancer-manager HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Since an `awk` and `perl` solutions are already provided, I wanted to try `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

## processing quoted input numbers

```
echo   1234   | awk '{                i=strtonum($1) ;  printf( "%s %d\n",$1, i)}'  # no problem
echo '"1234"' | awk '{                i=strtonum($1) ;  printf( "%s %d\n",$1, i)}'  # does not work
echo '"1234"' | awk '{ gsub("\"",""); i = $1         ;  printf( "%s %d\n",$1, i)}'  # works
```

Comment: Try to be a little bit more verbose in your answer

Comment: the only answer to mention awk's gsub; worked for my use case